# SAPUI5 -binding data to a chart inside a view repeater control

Tags: sapui5

Need a help on  SAPUI5, I am  trying to create a View as described below.
I am using the View repeater control and inside the View repeater control using the VIZ chart control .
The problem I am facing is not able to bind data to the chart though I am able to bind data to the repeater control.

Below is the JSON I use.

```
    "plants":[
            {
                            "plant":"Plant1",
                            "cCode":"***",
                            "Function":[
                                                            {"FunName":"fun1","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun2","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun3","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun4","Count":0},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun5","Count":11},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun6","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun7","Count":10}
                            ]

            },
            {
                            "plant":"Plant2",
                            "cCode":"***",
                            "Function":[
                                                            {"FunName":"fun1","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun2","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun3","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun4","Count":0},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun5","Count":11},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun6","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun7","Count":10}
                            ]


            }
            ]
```

}

My View:

```
createContent : function(oController) {
//  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
//  oModel.loadData("model/plantreport.json");
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
                                            "plants":[
           {
                            "plant":"Plant1",
                            "cCode":"10",
                            "Function":[
                                                            {"FunName":"fun1","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun2","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun3","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun4","Count":0},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun5","Count":11},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun6","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun7","Count":10}
                            ]

            },
            {
                            "plant":"Plant2",
                            "cCode":"20",
                            "Function":[
                                                            {"FunName":"fun1","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun2","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun3","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun4","Count":0},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun5","Count":11},
                                                            {"FunName":" fun6","Count":10},
                                                            {"FunName":"fun7","Count":10}
                            ]


            }
            ]



            });

    //////// CONTROL SECTION ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    //create view repeater title (optional)
    var oTitle_NoViews = new sap.ui.commons.Title({
        text:"Testing Please",
        level: sap.ui.commons.TitleLevel.H1
    });
var oLayout = new sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout();
    // create the row repeater control
    var oViewRepeater_NoViews = new sap.suite.ui.commons.ViewRepeater("vr_noViews",
    {  
            showViews: false,
            noData: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "Sorry, no data available!"}),
            showSearchField: false,
            showMoreSteps: 10, // you can use 'Show More' feature instead of paging

            //set view properties directly to the repeater
            responsive: false,
            itemMinWidth: 210,
            numberOfRows: 12
    });


    oViewRepeater_NoViews.bindAggregation("rows", {
        path : "/plants",
        factory : function(sId, oContext) {
            var sPath = oContext.sPath;  

       //Text
        control = new sap.ui.commons.TextView();
        control.bindProperty("text",oContext.sPath+"/plant");
        oLayout.addContent(control);
        //add content to cell, cell to row


        var oTemplate =  new sap.viz.ui5.data.DimensionDefinition({
                axis: 1,
                name : "Plant Name"
            });
            oTemplate.bindProperty("value", "FunName", function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    return value;
                }
            });

            var oTemplate2 =  new sap.viz.ui5.data.MeasureDefinition({
                name : "Count"
            });
            oTemplate2.bindProperty("value", "Count", function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    return value;
                }
                return 0;
            });

            var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
                            dimensions : [ oTemplate ],
                            measures : [ oTemplate2 ]
            });
            oDataset.bindAggregation("data", sPath + "/Function");

            var oBarChart = new sap.viz.ui5.Bar({
                            width : "300px",
                            height : "250px",
                            plotArea : {
                                xAxis : {

                                }
                            },
                            title : {
                                visible : true,
                                text : 'MY Graph'
                            },
                            dataset : oDataset
            });

            oLayout.addContent(oBarChart);
                return  oLayout;            
        }
    });

 oViewRepeater_NoViews.setModel(oModel);

     return new sap.m.Page({
            title: "Plant Report",
            showNavButton: "{device>/isPhone}",
            navButtonPress: [oController.doNavBack, oController],
            content: [oViewRepeater_NoViews],
            headerContent: [],
            footer: new sap.m.Bar({})
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you also share how you created the view repeater with charts, and how you set up the bindings? Without these, it's impossible to tell where it goes wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding for the VIZCharts is incorrect. It's probably copy-pasted since it also uses a named model `oModel`. Furthermore, you're starting from the absolute root `/plants` and then `/Function`, whereas you probably want to start from the relative path `Function` for the current `plants` element.

If you change the binding to a relative path: `data:{path:"Function"}` it should work (you may need to adapt the size of the chart to fit the view repeater block.)

By changing it to the relative path `Function`, it will take the data from the current `/plants` element.

Comment: no, this did not work, now i have used the factory function(see the updated view above), chart is not display on the load of the page but after click of the show more button , please help

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. It was just the binding that was wrong, and the sizing of the charts (they were too big to display). See this Gist for a working example: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b81bb024e79bdffe92bc

Comment: This works, but i still have a issue , i use split control and i have 2 links on the left have side only one page loads with the chart the other page does not load the chart.not sure what is wrong. will post my code soon.